# Import sources within a group must be alphabetized. Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have the ***Import sources within a group must be alphabetized.*** error in the following file:

**login.view.tsx**

```
import AbstractComponent from "../abstract-component";
import { LoginController } from "./login.view.controller";
import { UserService } from "../../services/user.service";
import { IBaseProps } from "../../App";

export interface ILoginProps extends IBaseProps {
    userService?: UserService;
  }

  class Login extends AbstractComponent<ILoginProps, object> {
    private loginController: LoginController;

    constructor(public props: Readonly<ILoginProps>) {
      super(props);
      this.loginController = new LoginController(this, props);
    }
}
```

My tsconfig.json is the following:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "rules": {
    "ordered-imports": [
      false
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

I tried to change the order of all the imports with results. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a typescript's error, but tslint's one. It wants you to rearrange the import statements in alphabetical order.

I think, like this (but I am not sure, so try different orders yourself):

```
import AbstractComponent from "../abstract-component";
import { IBaseProps } from "../../App";
import { LoginController } from "./login.view.controller";
import { UserService } from "../../services/user.service";
```

If nothing works, try tslint's auto fix command:

```
tslint --fix
```

If you use VSCode, then put the cursor on the red-underlined statements and press `ctrl + .`, it will suggest auto fix.

Comment: That order is not working..Also, VSCode doesn't not show me any red-underlined error so I am stuck.